# Primefaces p:overlayPanel is empty when update attribute is used in child tag

Tags: ajax, primefaces, xhtml

I want to show a list of key-value pairs in a datatable, where each pair is one row, inside an overlay panel. When a key-value pair is clicked, i want to update a `<p:inputText>`-Element, which is OUTSIDE the overlaypanel with the key-value of the selected row and simultaniously close the overlaypanel.

I just migrated from PF 4.0 to PF 6.1 and now im facing the issue, that whenever i use an update-attirbute inside the overlay panel, it appears to be empty and no content is shown.

here is an code example:

```
<p:inputText
        id="inputPvId"
        styleClass="form_input"
        readonly="true"
        value="#{bean.selectedValue.get(0)}" />
                <p:commandButton
                icon="ui-icon-link"
                id="selectValue"
                value="#{msg_properties.chooseValue}" />

                <p:overlayPanel
                        for="selectValue"
                        id="overlayValueSelector"
                        widgetVar="overlayValueSelector
                        dynamic="true"
                        styleClass="form_input_widest">

                        <p:dataTable
                                var="car"
                                value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
                                        <p:column
                                               headerText="Id">
                                                      <h:outputText
                                                             value="#{car.id}" />
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column
                                               headerText="Year">
                                                      <h:outputText
                                                             value="#{car.year}" />
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:ajax
                                               event="rowSelect"
                                               update=":form:inputPvId,:form:myTable"
                                               onsuccess="PF('overlayPV').hide()" />
                        </p:dataTable>
```

Previously it worked that way. All I changed is the way the Widget gets called from `"overlayPV".hide()"` to `"PF('overlayPV').hide()"` as the official Migration Guide suggested. If out cancel out the `update=":form:inputPvId,:form:myTable"` line in the ajax call, the content is shown properly.

Am I doing somethign wrong? My research showed, that other people also had trouble with the overlaypanel and the ajax update. However, i found no suitable solution for my problem.

I tried using the "`onRowClick`"-Attribute of the datable along with the widgetHide call like this:

```
<p:dataTable
        onRowClick="PF('overlayPV').hide()" />
```

and it worked fine, however i could not figure out how to update the `<p:inputText>`-Element with the choosen value. I had to refresh the page to show the new value. I would be happy if someone suggested a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue.

My initial problem was, that whenever an element inside the `<p:overlayPanel>` included the "update" attribute, the overlayPanel did not render any content and appeared empty.

i solved my issue with the `<p:remoteCommand>`-Tag, which I placed OUTSIDE of the overlayPanel as my example Code below shows:

```
<p:inputText
        id="inputPvId"
        styleClass="form_input"
        readonly="true"
        value="#{bean.selectedValue.get(0)}" />
                <p:commandButton
                icon="ui-icon-link"
                id="selectValue"
                value="#{msg_properties.chooseValue}" />

                <p:overlayPanel
                        for="selectValue"
                        id="overlayValueSelector"
                        widgetVar="overlayValueSelector
                        dynamic="true"
                        styleClass="form_input_widest">

                        <p:dataTable
                                var="myTable"
                                value="#{dtBasicView.cars}"
                                onRowClick="remoteCommand()">
                                        <p:column
                                               headerText="Id">
                                                      <h:outputText
                                                             value="#{car.id}" />
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column
                                               headerText="Year">
                                                      <h:outputText
                                                             value="#{car.year}" />
                                        </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
                 </p:overlayPanel>
                 <p:remoteCommand
                                        name="remoteCommand"
                                        update="inputPvId, myTable"                                         
                                        onsuccess="PF('overlayPV').hide()"/>
```

Note the onRowClick-Attribute of my dataTable which call the remoteCommand outside of te overlayPanel. The remoteCommand than updates all my Elements that need to be updated and also closes the overlayPanel.